# DataGridView column multiplication

Tags: c#, datagridview

please I want to multiply entries in a column with another column entries and the result will be in another column of the `DataGridView`.

please what's wrong with these:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
   int crsUn, cmb;
   for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
   {
       if (int.TryParse(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString(), out crsUn) && int.TryParse(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString(), out cmb))
       {
           int gp = crsUn * cmb; 
           dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value = gp.ToString();
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with this? What is the result it gives and what is the expected?

Comment: What happens it works sometimes and sometimes not? or not at all works?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the full column filled with the calculation on all rows, it might be better to calculate this in the data source and then just have the dataGridView display the results including the calculated column.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is where your event occurs. And maybe you want to fire it on data bound or whatever..